# AngularJs - CORS - WithCredentials Dilemma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, cors

I have an API which servers two apps, one mobile and the other one web.

I'm using token based authentication to make it secure and in my web app works perfectly. However in my mobile app is not. And the thing is that in my webpage I have the same domain as my api, therefore no CORS issue.

In my mobile app I need to send my credentials to validate the user's token because as I don't have the same domain is not sending automatically.

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  }]);
```

But te dilemma is, if I send the credendials usisng the code above I get:

```
 The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'
```

Because I have this set: headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*', where is supposed to be a specific domain but being a mobile app I don't have any.

If I remove all CORS validations I get other errors...
I don't know what to do... how to face this issue.

My Api was made using Ruby, and to validate the authentication I'm using this code:

```
def authenticate_current_user
    head :unauthorized if get_current_user.nil?
  end

  def get_current_user
    return nil unless cookies[:auth_headers]
    auth_headers = JSON.parse(cookies[:auth_headers])

    expiration_datetime = DateTime.strptime(auth_headers["expiry"], "%s")
    current_user = User.find_by(uid: auth_headers["uid"])

    if current_user &&
       current_user.tokens.has_key?(auth_headers["client"]) &&
       expiration_datetime > DateTime.now

      @current_user = current_user
    end
    @current_user
  end
```

If I set WithCredentials to false I get 401 unauthorized coz cookie[auth_headers] is empty.

Comment: I was working on a similar, but different issue the other day and I read something to the effect that if you set withCredentials that you must specify the domain....ie...the wildcard cannot be used.   Maybe it also overrides the need/check for CORS also???

Comment: Sorry, copied the wrong link....this is the right one....the other one is the one that lead me to this one.

https://github.com/joostfarla/serverless-cors-plugin/issues/1

Comment: why do you need cookies for token based auth?

Comment: @charlietfl my ruby code is expecting a cookie: "return nil unless cookies[:auth_headers]"

Comment: Might want to read https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/token-based-authentication-with-ruby-on-rails-5-api